# Divergence and curl for vector field $F$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a straight forward divergence and curl question

Let $F$ be the vector field defined as

$$F=(ax^{2}+bxy+cy^{2}-2x)i + (x^{2}+xy-y^{2}+bz)j+ (2y+2z)k$$

Determine $a,b,c$ since the vector field is solenodial, hence for this I have $a=-0.5, b=2$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Now dertermine a,b,c since the vector Field is irrptational, hence for this I have, $b=2, c=0.5$ and now $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Lastly fix the values of a,b,c such that the vector field f is both solenodial and irrotational and check that the vector field satisfies the Laplace equation. However for this, I have chosen my $a=-0.5, b=2$, and $c=0.5$, then when computing the Laplace equation $\neq 0$, I must have gone wrong somewhere, any help would be most appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your results are correct, but the Laplace equation is indeed satisfied:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta F_x&=&\Delta(ax^2+cy^2)=2a+2c=0\;,\\
\Delta F_y&=&\Delta(x^2-y^2)=2-2=0\;,\\
\Delta F_z&=&\Delta(2y+2z)=0\;.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Perfect Have my head around it now, many thanks.